# Rest jaxrs json object format incorrect (looks like a list) when using java.io.Serializable capable pojo

Tags: json, ajax

I have a pojo that I load into a database with hibernate.

```
    @Entity
    @XmlRootElement
    @IdClass(EventCause.class)
    public class EventCause implements Serializable {
```

I am returning a list of these pojos in a rest API

```
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("/{imsi}") 
    public Response getAllEventAndCauseCodeByImsi(@PathParam("imsi") final long imsi) {
        final List<EventCause> imsiEventList = callDataDao.getEventAndCauseCodeByIMSI(imsi);
        return Response.status(200).entity(imsiEventList).build();
    }
```

However jaxrs Json conversion on the rest API is not marshaling this to standard object format

It is coming out as a json response but in format ….

[
    [
        12,
        4097,
        "RRC CONN SETUP-REJECT DUE TO OVERLOAD"
    ],
    [
        0,
        4098,
        "S1 SIG CONN SETUP-SUCCESS"
    ]
]

Instead of something like

[EventCause : 
{"eventId":"12", 
"causeCode":"4097", 
"description":"RRC CONN SETUP-REJECT DUE TO OVERLOAD"},
EventCause : 
{"eventId":"0", 
"causeCode":"4098", 
"description":"S1 SIG CONN SETUP-SUCCESS"}]

Why is this.
Note I have passed another test POJO across same API without "implements Serializable" and that does come out in a standard json object format, so looks like this Serializable capability is causing this difference.

Env info : java 1.8, running on wildfly 18 (tried Wildfly 10 and same thing)
jaxrs in pom....

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found problem,
was not to do with serialization, or @Entity

I was not explicitly mapping my DB response to the pojo response I had tagged as an @XMLRootElement, 
so JaxRS count not marshal it properly and it was just returning the arraylist that the DB was returning.

I'm not looking at tighter solution where responses are mapped directly to my pojo formats, and this adhere strictly to the REST API I require.